# Using Java-Eclipse SDK, How can I Take 2 numbers as input

Tags: eclipse

I am a beginner. 
Using Java-Eclipse SDK, How can I Take 2 numbers as input, print the sum?
I cannot open a project! Please can some one help me, telling me step by step what to do?

Thanks..
Tanvir

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to create a Java project, take two numbers as output, and print the sum? If that is true, you should really read over some basic Java/Eclipse tutorials. I would suggest the [Eclipse and Java Tutorial for Total Beginners](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/totalbeginner.html) -- it should get you started on how to create/open a project and how to use eclipse.

As for getting two numbers and printing out the sum, you should *really* learn Java IO and do this yourself, but a quick google search gets exactly what you want:

```
import java.io.*; //imports java.io class 

/* 
 * Adds 2 integers given by the user, then prints out the sum. 
 * Directly copied from http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet492.htm, as I 
 * am too lazy to write this myself :)
 */ 

public class Add2number { 

  //main(): application entry point 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

        //set input stream 
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader( 
              new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

        //get numbers from user input 
        //asks user for 1st number, then converts it to an integer 
        System.out.print("Enter first integer: "); 
        int x = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine()); 
        //asks user for 2nd number, than converts it to an integer 
        System.out.print("Enter second integer: "); 
        int y = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine()); 

        //add x,y 
        int sum = x + y; 

        //Display sum of x,y 
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum); 
  }//ends main 

}//ends addReadLine
```